# what is FlinkZooKeeperQuorumPeer for in flink?

Tags: apache-flink

in bin/flink-console.sh, FlinkZooKeeperQuorumPeer is listed as one of the service that flink that can run. What is FlinkZooKeeperQuorumPeer for? In which flink needs to use zookeeper and run a standalone service for it?  If it is for job manager high availability, why don't we put as part of job manager?

```
   (zookeeper)

CLASS_TO_RUN=org.apache.flink.runtime.zookeeper.FlinkZooKeeperQuorumPeer
;;
```

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation states `FlinkZooKeeperQuorumPeer` is a simple wrapper for ZooKeeper's `QuorumPeer`. `QuorumPeer` is the class that is responsible for managing the quorum protocol, which is used for leader election mechanism. The Zookeeper's election mechanism is used in case of JobManager High Availability mode set to `zookeeper`. Basically, in this mode You will have multiple JobManagers running, but only one of them will be marked as a `leader`  and it will be really the only one responsible for scheduling the jobs. If the leader for some reason dies or becomes unresponsive then the election is performed using Zookepeer's election mechanism and new leader is elected. More on High Availability in found [here.](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.8/ops/jobmanager_high_availability.html) And more on the Zookeepers election itself [here.](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/current/recipes.html#sc_leaderElection)